# Zip files inside without including main folder In android java

Tags: java, android

im using this code it perfectly create zip files for example i have folder

sdcard/music and when i create xxx.zip file it creates .zip file includes music/songs and also some sub folders in it

but i want to exclude "music" the main Folder in the .zip file and want it to start directly including all songs and subfolders in it,how to do it

i use this way but it takes main folder name as well when zipping

```
public void unzipbutton(View v){ // button click

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/songs.zip");
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            addDirToZipArchive(zos, new File("/mnt/sdcard/music"), null);
                zos.flush();
                fos.flush();
                zos.close();
                fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

     public static void addDirToZipArchive(ZipOutputStream zos, File fileToZip, String parrentDirectoryName) throws Exception {
        if (fileToZip == null || !fileToZip.exists()) {
            return;
        }

        String zipEntryName = fileToZip.getName();
        if (parrentDirectoryName!=null && !parrentDirectoryName.isEmpty()) {
            zipEntryName = parrentDirectoryName + "/" + fileToZip.getName();
        }

        if (fileToZip.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("+" + zipEntryName);
            for (File file : fileToZip.listFiles()) {
                addDirToZipArchive(zos, file, zipEntryName);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("   " + zipEntryName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(zipEntryName));
            int length;
            while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();
            fis.close();
        }
    }
```

anybody help on this,thanks

this has been so tricky till now no way works at the moments for me :/

Comment: addDirToZipArchive(zos, new File("/mnt/sdcard/music/") ?

Comment: i tried this before but did not work bro :( it add that music folder in the zip file always

Comment: Maybe `String parrentDirectoryName` parameter is there for some reason?

Comment: this is only used "parrentDirectoryName" when i define addDirToZipArchive(zos, new File("/mnt/sdcard/music"), "New Folder"); if i kept it null it wont execute :)

Comment: anybody got success in it ?

Comment: Why u need this? Because there is option available to add folder in zip. But still you want then you have to develop you own way like read music folder first get list of file. Depend on files check if it is file or dictionary add in zip. If dictionary then again get list of file n add in zip... In this way you r able all files from music folder to zip.

Comment: i did not get you sorry

Answer (score 0):

In your ZipEntry check the full path of zipEntryName, it must be something like: "music/Pink/try.mp3" just invoke a substring in order to obtain as zipEntryName "Pink/try.mp3", your zip file will be the same "songs.zip" but inside of it you'll find the folder "Pink" instead the main folder "music/Pink..."

It worked for me.

Comment: i do not even want pink folder i want direct files in it